# Convert a Python POST request to Android

Tags: java, android, python, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to use this example of a Python POST to an API in my android project. I do not have much experience with HttpsURLConnection but I think this is what I need to use to accomplish this. I have looked at tutorials for this but I am not sure how to integrate this Python code. This is the Python:

```
# highly suggested to use the requests package
# http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/
import requests
# read in the image and construct the payload
image = open("example.jpg").read()
data = {"api_key": "KH8hdoai0wrjB0LyeA3EMu5n4icwyOQo"}
files = {"image": open("example.jpg")}
# fire off the request
r = requests.post("http://www.idmypill.com/api/id/", data = data, files = files)
# contents will be returned as a JSON string
print r.content
```

This is what I have so far on trying to convert this to Android but I am not sure at all if this will work or is the right way to go about this.

```
// HTTP POST request
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://www.idmypill.com/api/id/";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection IDMyPill = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    IDMyPill.setRequestMethod("POST");


    String urlParameters = "";

    // Send post request
    IDMyPill.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(IDMyPill.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = IDMyPill.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(IDMyPill.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with python but I suggest you output the api to a json same behavior with php json_encode(); if there is in python. Then use android-volley for calling since its much simpler.

Comment: Go ahead and try out what will happen if you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

For REST Webservices I recommend using https://github.com/47deg/appsly-android-rest . It has an easy to use api and you don't have to care a lot about the backend part.
I hope you only want to get the data in your android app. But if you only want to translate your method this may not be the correct for you :)